# How do I stop the wallpaper from changing constantly?

Tags: desktop-background

Why is Ubuntu continually changing wallpapers? Is there a way to stop it? The wallpaper section in the *system configuration* mentions no such option.

Comment: Please add some more detail. I don't think you're talking about rotating custom wallpapers since that was a pain to get to work. So, what kind of wallpaper do you have, want kind do you want (custom photo/default available) and what does ubuntu change it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the desktop and choosing change desktop background and choose one that you like that does not appear in a stack. If it looks like a stack of pictures, then it's a slideshow and it'll keep changing.

*Right-clicking on the desktop and choosing* ***Change Desktop background*** *will bring up the window that you see below. The image selected in the screenshot is a single image whereas the one below it(the one of scyscrapers) is a slideshow. Choosing an image that's not a slideshow will solve your problem*

[image]